# how to hidden a taxonomy menu item use hook?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes, users

I have built a web site which has a content type call product and  product taxonomy

product taxonomy has sat a boolin function makes user select to show up for anonymous user or not

If the user selected the taxonomy parent boolin function the taxonomy parent has disappeared form the menu system.

When the user selected the taxonomy boolin function I want to hide the taxonomy parent link

this is my code

```
function hellosanta_menu_alter(&$items){
    $items['taxonomy/term/82']['access callback'] =  False;
    $items['taxonomy/term/82']['type']=MENU_CALLBACK;
}
```

I have got nothing for this